# Ubuntu One indicator for GNOME Shell panel?

Tags: ubuntu-one, software-recommendation, gnome, indicator

Is there any shell extension for an Ubuntu One indicator in the top panel for gnome 3 shell?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such extension for GNOME 3. You are free to write one, however. :)

Comment: i just fixed it myself. 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-indicator

start ubuntu one and refresh gnome shell.

Comment: This applet does not work, because there seem to be problems with dependencies. If you want to install this package and have the package indicator-ubuntuone installed,then the package ubuntuone-indicator claims to depend on indicator-ubuntuone. But if you press "install", then it wants to remove the package indicator-ubuntuone!! This needs to be fixed. I also put message up in Launchpad for you and the Bug-reporter!! Please fix this up!! Greetings
Linuxexperte